# How to update existing profiles in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models `profile` and `review`. I have added score column in `profile` model. Following code is calculating and updating `score` but i have 1000s of profiles already in the database and i don't know how do i update the score of existing profiles.

Your help is much appreciated.

**Profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    # :phone
    # :slogan
    # :description
    # :score

    has_many :reviews
    before_save :update_score
    private
      def update_score
        self.score += 1  if changes['phone'] && changes['phone'].first.nil?
        self.score += 1  if changes['slogan'] && changes['slogan'].first.nil?
        self.score += 1  if changes['description'] && changes['description'].first.nil?
      end
end
```

**Review.rb**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile

  # :body
  after_save :update_profile_score
  private
    def update_profile_score
      self.profile.score += 1
      self.profile.save
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't simply something like this in `rails console` work?

```
Review.all.each{|r| r.save}
Profile.all.each{|p| p.save}
```

The thing is that your code doens't make a lot of sense... you want that every time a review is *saved* to update the profile score? That means every time someone updates the review the profile score goes up? This looks wrong.

Also `update_score` in Profile looks weird and doens't make a lot of sense.

It'd be *much* better if you explained what score you are trying to calculate and on what it depends on, I have a feeling the real solution would be quite different.

Comment: i tried in console but it didnt worked btw actually user cant update the `review` thats why i kept this way.

Comment: Explain "didn't work". Maybe you forgot to select the correct enviroment (e.g `rails console production`). But answer the question about what you're trying to do please :)

Comment: in console `Review.all.each{|r| r.save}` is updating the score but `Profile.all.each{|p| p.save}` doesn't update the score. i think there is something wrong in `update_score` method

Comment: For Review you want `after_create` by the way.

Comment: About Profile, what is `update_score`'s goal? it looks like you want to update the score only if something was changed, but that looks weird to me. Maybe you meant `self.score +=1 unless self.phone.blank?` (add to score if value is not empty). Again please describe the end goal

Comment: i want to add one time value 1 in score on adding phone value but doesnt want to add score on updating profile.

Comment: i have made change in `update_score` `self.score += 1  if !self.slogan.blank?` and than in console i run `Profile.all.each {|p| p.save}` it worked and updated the records. after doing this i ll change the code again so score value wont increase everytime user update their profile.\

Comment: If you want something like `self.score += 1 if self.phone_changed? && self.phone_was.nil?`. Good luck! More info at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html